# Ubuntu 100% swap usage all the time

Tags: ubuntu, memory, monitoring, swap

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my VPS. I using server mainly to running web scrapers in python. Other things are django project hosted by Docker, postgreSQL database. I using netdata tool to monitoring usage of whole system. I noticed that my swap usage is always 100%, undependently of how much scrapers/processes working in the same time. It is normal or something is going wrong with the memory?

My netdata general charts, when a few scrapers working (low load):

[image: Low load]

My netdata general charts, when a lot scrapers working (big load):

[image: Big load]

```
/etc/netdata# cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty]
md2 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0]
      523200 blocks [2/1] [U_]

md3 : active raid1 nvme0n1p3[0]
      437971904 blocks [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 4/4 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          64362        2782        1394         294       60184       60645
Swap:           510         510
```

My swapiness value = 60 (default).

It's normal situation for Linux?

Comment: The statistics you show say you are using 500MB of `swap` for 64GB of RAM.  Some recommendations say you should have 4GB - 8GB of swap space for 64GB of RAM.  Some say as much as 1.5x more `swap` space then RAM if you need hibernation capabilities.  The reality is that your memory usage is not high from your posted statistics.  If the maxed out `swap` space does not cause problems, you probably do not need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks @GracefulRestart :)